# How can I convert DataRow to string Array?

Tags: c#, datarow

I have some values in a `DataGridRow` (item Array) and I want to fetch all these values into a string array. How can I achieve this?

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(k);
            DataRowView Drv = (DataRowView)row.Item;
            DataRow dr = (DataRow)Drv.Row;
```

Comment: What is the content of you data rows? The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One possibility is to call `dr.ItemArray;` This will get you a `object[]`. Then you have to cast each object to `string` before you use it.

Answer (score 32):

```
var rowAsString = string.Join(", ", dataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray);
```

No need of any lambda expresion as above.

Answer (score 10):

LINQ adds some sugar:

```
var stringArray = dr.ItemArray.Cast<string>().ToArray()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var rowAsString = string.Join(", ", dr.ItemArray.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray());
```

This should give you a string with each item in your data row separated by a comma.

Comment: Only acceptable answer. Other answers will throw error if and of item aren't string type.

Comment: How does this work?! DataRow (dr) has no Select (and definately no Selct ;-) )

Comment: :-) Oops! There was two typos in the answer. First, i had forgotten to access the ItemArray and second the method name should of course be Select ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
string[] months = string.Join(",", dataTable.Rows[0].ItemArray).Split(',').ToArray();
```